# Diff without changes when reviewing a suggested edit - Bug?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, diff

I'm reviewing [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9854862), I was up to *Skip* it, but then I thought: if I can't see the change wouldn't anyone else have the same problem? How To deal with this?

Comment: Looks like it might be some weird newline changes. If you view the `Markdown Diff` it shows some extra newlines at the bottom being added. I don't know why it's showing all of the spacing differences though.

Comment: @DaveZych Seems a tab vs spaces change of the code. The Markdown view definitively helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like a tabs vs spaces vs newlines diff. If you view the `Markdown` diff it shows some differences.

[image]